# Java Windows UTF-8 (unicode) Printing

Tags: java, windows, unicode, printing, utf-8

I have the problem that when you are in windows and you try to print through JAVA you can only use the AUTOSENSE property.
However my string that I want to get printed is in greek => UTF-8. When I turn the AUTOSENSE to TEXT_PLAIN_UTF8 i get an: sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor exception....

Any suggestions? Or other way of printing in Unicode?
thanks!

```
    String datastr = "UNICODE STRING";
    byte[] databa = null;
    try {
        databa = datastr.getBytes("UTF8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_16;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    if (databa != null) {
        DocPrintJob pjob = service.createPrintJob();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(databa, docFlavor, null);
        try {
            pjob.print(doc, aset);
        } catch (PrintException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

if i try to print it in STRING.TEXT_PLAIN and also in everything else than AUTOSENSE, i get this:

```
sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
```

Finally the supported Flavors are these...

```
Win32 Printer : HP Deskjet 5440 Series Flavors:
    image/gif; class="[B"
    image/gif; class="java.io.InputStream"
    image/gif; class="java.net.URL"
    image/jpeg; class="[B"
    image/jpeg; class="java.io.InputStream"
    image/jpeg; class="java.net.URL"
    image/png; class="[B"
    image/png; class="java.io.InputStream"
    image/png; class="java.net.URL"
    application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"
    application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"
    application/octet-stream; class="[B"
    application/octet-stream; class="java.net.URL"
    application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"
```

Comment: We have to guess, since you didn't include the full stack trace. First, you're doing UTF-8, but your example is using `TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_16`. Instead you should try the `...UTF_8` enum. Also, did you try `DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;` on the original string, bypassing the whole explicit UTF-8 byte array conversion? If the error still occurs, then the problem is in what you are *not* showing us.

Comment: I cannot use the string text plain option in windows only for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to do it with SWT here is the code...

```
package printer;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.printing.Printer;
import org.eclipse.swt.printing.PrinterData;

public class TextPrinter {

    Printer printer;
    GC gc;
    int lineHeight = 0;
    int tabWidth = 0;
    int leftMargin;
    int rightMargin;
    int topMargin, bottomMargin;
    int x;
    int y;
    int index;
    int end;
    String tabs;
    StringBuffer wordBuffer;

    public TextPrinter() {
    }

    public void printString(final String textToPrint) {

        PrinterData data = Printer.getDefaultPrinterData();
        printer = new Printer(data);
        Thread printingThread = new Thread("Printing") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                print(printer, textToPrint);
                printer.dispose();
            }
        };
        printingThread.start();
    }

    void print(Printer printer, String textToPrint) {
        if (printer.startJob("iassael")) { 

            Rectangle clientArea = printer.getClientArea();
            Rectangle trim = printer.computeTrim(0, 0, 0, 0);
            Point dpi = printer.getDPI();
            leftMargin = dpi.x + trim.x; // one inch from left side of paper
            rightMargin = clientArea.width - dpi.x + trim.x + trim.width; 
            topMargin = dpi.y + trim.y; // one inch from top edge of paper
            bottomMargin = clientArea.height - dpi.y + trim.y + trim.height;

            /* Create a buffer for computing tab width. */
            int tabSize = 4; // is tab width a user setting in your UI?
            StringBuffer tabBuffer = new StringBuffer(tabSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < tabSize; i++)
                tabBuffer.append(' ');
            tabs = tabBuffer.toString();

            /*
             * Create printer GC, and create and set the printer font &
             * foreground color.
             */
            gc = new GC(printer);

            Font font = new Font(null, "Helvetica", 11, SWT.NORMAL);
            gc.setFont(font);
            tabWidth = gc.stringExtent(tabs).x;
            lineHeight = gc.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

            /* Print text to current gc using word wrap */
            printText(textToPrint);
            printer.endJob();

            /* Cleanup graphics resources used in printing */
            font.dispose();
            gc.dispose();
        }
    }

    void printText(String textToPrint) {
        printer.startPage();
        wordBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        x = leftMargin;
        y = topMargin;
        index = 0;
        end = textToPrint.length();
        while (index < end) {
            char c = textToPrint.charAt(index);
            index++;
            if (c != 0) {
                if (c == 0x0a || c == 0x0d) {
                    if (c == 0x0d && index < end
                            && textToPrint.charAt(index) == 0x0a) {
                        index++; // if this is cr-lf, skip the lf
                    }
                    printWordBuffer();
                    newline();
                } else {
                    if (c != '\t') {
                        wordBuffer.append(c);
                    }
                    if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                        printWordBuffer();
                        if (c == '\t') {
                            x += tabWidth;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (y + lineHeight <= bottomMargin) {
            printer.endPage();
        }
    }

    void printWordBuffer() {
        if (wordBuffer.length() > 0) {
            String word = wordBuffer.toString();
            int wordWidth = gc.stringExtent(word).x;
            if (x + wordWidth > rightMargin) {
                /* word doesn't fit on current line, so wrap */
                newline();
            }
            gc.drawString(word, x, y, false);
            x += wordWidth;
            wordBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        }
    }

    void newline() {
        x = leftMargin;
        y += lineHeight;
        if (y + lineHeight > bottomMargin) {
            printer.endPage();
            if (index + 1 < end) {
                y = topMargin;
                printer.startPage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8`.

Comment: Also can you paste the whole stacktrace

Comment: Yes but when i get the flavors that my printer supports it only supports autosense although its not old. Any other options or another library i could use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For auto_sense you could write a BOM character (**\uFEFF**) in front of the text. This is a zero-width space, used for marking a text as unicode.